# How to control 1 servo with 2 potentiometer?

Tags: servo, potentiometer

I have been building a RC plane completely from scratch using an arduino but I am fairly new to this.

Essentially I have been able to make my two arduinos communicate with each other so that when one joystick is moved, the brushless motor is activated, and when the other joystick is moved up or down, 2 servos are activated to push my plane flaps up or down.
The problem I am running into is I am not sure how to control the same servo motors when I move the joystick left and right. Ideally when moved left, one servo would push a flap up and the other down, and vice versa.

The closest thing I have come across on the internet is using a push button to switch between the two control methods but I would ideally like everything to work more smoothly together w/o the push button if that makes sense.

If anyone has any ideas what to write in my code please let me know or if I need to clarify anything else.

Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: joystick up-down and joystick left-right are two separate, independent controls

Comment: try reading on the finite state mashine. In simple programs like this it would help yyou manage different states.
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/tolentinocotesta/let-s-learn-how-to-use-finite-state-machine-with-arduino-c524ac?ref=part&ref_id=8233&offset=13

Comment: you are probably trying to do `read joystick1, move servo1 ... read joystick2, move servo1 somehow` ..... instead use variables ...  `read joystick1, set variable value ... read joystick2, adjust variable value ... use final variable value to move servo1`

Comment: Flaps or Ailerons? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxrdhJanotw

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure that your inputs and outputs are separated in code. This means that the inputs (like the joystick potis) only change variables in your code. Then below the input code block you output these variables to the servos and motors. This makes the code in your situation easier, since the inputs don't trigger actions, but only set the variables for the actions, which then get executed by another code block.

Your up-down joystick sets the position for the flaps (as you have already coded). The left-right joystick then only creates a deflection from that position. You can code this like the following (in pseudo code):

```
Read up-down joystick
Map value from analog value to range 0 to 180 and save in variable "flap_pos"
Read left-right joystick
Map value from analog value to range -90 to 90 and save in variable "flap_deflection"
Write servo1 value as "flap_pos+deflection"
Write servo2 value as `flap_pos-flap_deflection"
```

Note that `flap_deflection` can be negative or positive (depending on joystick direction) and can thus deflect in both directions. And the different signs in the servo commands make sure that the deflection will behave inverted between the servos (one side moving down when the other is moving up). You will need to adjust the value mapping depending on your flap hardware. And you might want to restrain the values to a specific range (also depending on your hardware).

As you can see there is no `if` statement or similar in the pseudo code above. All the magic is in the mapping of the read analog values and the addition and subtraction.

Comment: Like the idea of pseudo code. The only reason why I am not marking up is becuase the question does not contain enough question to have a correct answer

Comment: There is no real magic, it is just simple math. :-D In "the good ol' days" analog mixers did what you describe digitally. Anyway, good answer, even if it reveals that (young) developers lost a lot of knowledge today.